# My Laravel test is returning a 302 redirect rather than a 403 forbidden status

Tags: php, laravel, testing

I have a Model called `Type` with a `title` field and a `pretty_slug` field.

I have a test that is checking that a user can not update a `Type` instance:

```php
    <?
    public function test_user_cannot_put_update_page() {
        $type = Type::factory()->make([
            'title' => 'Original type',
        ]);
        $type->save();

        $response = $this->put(route('types.update', [
            'pretty_slug' => $type->pretty_slug,
            'title' => 'New type',
        ]));
        $response->assertForbidden();

        $this->assertDatabaseHas('types', [
            'title' => 'Original type'
        ]);
    }
```

If I do `dd($response->getContent());` I can see that a redirect is happening:

[image]

Now the weird thing is that I have the exact same for another Model called `Level`:

```php
    <?
    public function test_user_cannot_put_update_page() {
        $level = Level::factory()->make([
            'title' => 'Original level',
        ]);
        $level->save();

        $response = $this->put(route('levels.update', [
            'pretty_slug' => $level->pretty_slug,
            'title' => 'New level',
        ]));
        $response->assertForbidden();

        $this->assertDatabaseHas('levels', [
            'title' => 'Original level'
        ]);
    }
```

The Model `Level` is exactly the same as `Type`: the same Controller, the same Trait shared, same Policy, same Tests, same routes… I have other Models called `Idea`, `Concept` and `Episode` that have the exact same behavior.

All tests pass, except for my `Type` Model:

[image]

I have no idea why this particular `types.update` route is not working. It should return a `302` but is instead redirecting.

It is working when I use the webform: the `Type` instance updates correctly. But the test is failing.

How can I debug this test? Where do I look for an issue in my code?
Thanks for any help.

EDIT 1: added controller and routes

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you show us the controller and the routes?

Comment: @Aless55 I've updated my post. As you can see, the controller method and the route structure are identical for both `Type` and `Level` models.

Comment: are you sure that authorize()  is working fine?

Comment: Actually @Aless55 I looked into the `StoreType` file, and I had `'order' => 'required|numeric'`. I changed it to `'order' => 'numeric',` so that the `order` wasn't required. And… it worked. It seems when I tried calling `types.update`, I didn't include an `order` field, so it probably redirect to the same form.

Comment: I ended up changing my test to include the `order` field, while keeping that field required. Many thanks @Aless55 for showing me the way.

Comment: I am glad you found the problem, sometimes the little things take up the most time

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is the `'levels.update'` route might be protected by the `auth` middleware.

Since there is no user logged in, the `auth` middleware will attempt to redirect to the login page instead.

Comment: The `levels.update` works fine. It's the `types.update` that is causing a problem. And there is no `auth` middleware enabled for those routes.

Answer (score 0):

I like IGP's answer. But if that's not it, you might want to check your host configs. Apache or Nginx, or whatever you're using. It could be the route is being called via http and your server is redirecting to https, or visa versa.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Aless55, I found the issue: it was the validation of my `Type` model that was preventing me from updating the instance.

I looked into the `StoreType` file, in which I had:

```php
'order' => 'required|numeric',
```

This means the `order` field is required. But when I tried calling the `types.update` route, I wasn't including that field.

One solution would have been to make that field optional. But I ended up including the `order` field in my test:

```php
$response = $this->put(route('types.update', [
    'pretty_slug' => $type->pretty_slug,
    'title' => 'Alex new type',
    'order' => 1,
]));
```